# Retrieving count of column values based on another column value

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am new to python and working on data analysis using pandas, I have a dataframe similar to one below,

```
col1 col2
a     10
b     20
a     30
a     15
c     10
b     10
```

Need to find sum of all values for col2 for each unique value in col1

Something like this:

```
a  55
b  30
c  10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.groupby(['col1']).agg(['sum']) .. this should work

else df.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].sum()

Comment: Thanks a lot Soubhik, df.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].sum() worked :)